# How to convert Vec<T> to HashMap<T,T>?

Tags: rust

I have a vector of strings.I need to convert it to HashMap.

Vector's 0 elements should become a key and 1 element should become a value. The same for 2, 3, and so on.

The obvious solution, just to make a for loop and add them to HashMap one by one. However, it will end up several lines of code. I am curious whether there is a cleaner, one-liner.

I know you can do vec.to_iter().collect(). However, this requires a vector to have tuples (vs a flat vector).

Comment: Have you tried `itertools`'s `tuples()`?

Comment: Do you mean a `HashSet`? Are you trying to map vector indices to elements? Are you trying to do `vec.into_iter().map(|x| (x, x)).collect::<HashMap<_, _>>()`?

Comment: This question needs a [mcve] showing the "obvious solution" with some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `chunks_exact` plus a few combinators to achieve this. However, I wouldn't recommend putting this on only one line for readability reasons. This does have a downside, and that is extra elements (if the vector has an odd number of elements) will be discarded.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    // vector with elements
    let vector = vec!["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

    let map = vector.chunks_exact(2) // chunks_exact returns an iterator of slices
    .map(|chunk| (chunk[0], chunk[1])) // map slices to tuples
    .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>(); // collect into a hashmap

    // outputs: Map {"e": "f", "c": "d", "a": "b"}
    println!("Map {:?}", map);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`slice::array_chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.array_chunks) is currently unstable but when it's stabilized in the future, I would prefer this over `.chunks(2)`:

```
#![feature(array_chunks)]

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    let map = vec
        .array_chunks::<2>()
        .map(|[k, v]| (k, v))
        .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
    dbg!(map);
}
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:11] map = {
    1: 2,
    3: 4,
    5: 6,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=10024474166d48c3a3b5250c83159752)

Answer (score 2):

Using [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools)'s [tuples](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.3/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuples):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;
use std::collections::HashMap;


fn main() {
    let v: Vec<String> = vec!["key1".into(), "val1".into(), "key2".into(), "val2".into()];

    // Extra elements are discarded
    let hm: HashMap<String, String> = v.into_iter().tuples().collect();
    
    assert_eq!(hm, HashMap::from([("key1".into(), "val1".into()), ("key2".into(), "val2".into())]));
}
```